# Can someone breakdown what does nums[i] = nums[i-1] + nums[i] do? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

So I'm trying to understand what the 'nums[i] =' portion does. I do know that it's the index of nums at those value that 'i' is. But why am I assigning or setting it equal to the math part of the code?

I was looking at other ways to solve leetcode problem #1480 and found this and thought it looked more efficient than what I wrote and I got puzzled trying to dissect what its it being set equal to something.

Here's the code that I was looking at that was puzzling me.

```
nums = [1,1,1,1,1,1]



def runningSum(nums: list[int]) -> list[int]:
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            # print(nums[i])
            nums[i] = nums[i-1] + nums[i]
            print(nums[i])
        return nums



print(runningSum(nums))
```

So I know 'nums[i-1]' would take the previous index and add it to the current index '+ nums[i]'. But how does that correlate with assigning it to 'nums[i]'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please explain what your question is exactly?

Comment: You're replacing the current value of `nums[i]` (which originally is `1`) with the sum of all the previous values in the list plus 1.

Comment: It reassigns the current item to be the sum of the current item plus the previous item.

Comment: When you write `nums[i] = SOMETHING`, whatever the `SOMETHING` is gets assigned to `nums[i]`.  It doesn't behave differently based on what specifically `SOMETHING` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums[i] = nums[i-1] + nums[i]
```

The right-hand side of the equation is evaluated *first*, before anything is assigned.

So, the code calculates the sum of the current list element `nums[i]` and the previous list element `nums[i-1]`.

Then, the current list element `nums[i]` is replaced with that new value.